# how to get the most recent date from the file names

Tags: r

I have those folders with names of dates under "c:/Document/"

[image]

I wonder whether there is a way that I can auto read the most recent date folder in?

Such as get the latest folder names and `datadate<-XXX`, and then my input can auto point to the most recent folder by `input_dir <-Paste0("c:/Document/", datadate, "/")` In my example, it will be `20210823` for the `datadate`.

any suggestions or better way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function `list.files(path = path,pattern = pattern)` to get the name of your folders,
where tou can define a path and pattern for the name of your folders. After that you could:

## Example

```
folders <- c("20210603","20210625","20210823")

max_date_folder <-
  folders %>% 
  sort() %>% 
  tail(1)

path <- "C:/Documents"

input_dir <- file.path(path,max_date_folder)

input_dir

[1] "C:/Documents/20210823"
```

Comment: `list.files()` should include the `include.dirs = TRUE` argument.

Comment: may I ask how should I define the pattern? if under dir, we have those date folder and some other files, such as `data.bat`?

Comment: It will depend of the names in your path, for example, if date folders are the only ones with numbers in their a names, you could use `[0-9]+` as a pattern. I do not know your context, but consider using R Project and a separate folder for the data.

Answer (score 2):

We may use `file.info` to find the most recent ones opened with `ctime` etc

```
 input_dir[which.max(file.info(input_dir)$ctime)]
```